# conversion of elements in dataframe to string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to convert bytes to string in dataframe.

```
data['CleanedText'].head()
0    b'witti littl book make son laugh loud recit c...
1    b'grew read sendak book watch realli rosi movi...
2    b'fun way children learn month year learn poem...
3    b'great littl book read nice rhythm well good ...
4    b'book poetri month year goe month cute littl ...
Name: CleanedText, dtype: object
```

I am using normal **for loop** to do this but it is taking too much time to convert.

```
for i,j in enumerate(text_data):
    data['newtext'][i] = text_data[i].decode('utf-8')
```

Is there anyway to convert bytes to string using **numpy** as it is computationally fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.decode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.str.decode.html)

```
>>> df.CleanedText.str.decode('utf-8')

0    witti littl book make son laugh loud recit c...
1    grew read sendak book watch realli rosi movi...
2    fun way children learn month year learn poem...
3    great littl book read nice rhythm well good ...
4    book poetri month year goe month cute littl ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply()` plus [Lambda functions](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html):

```
data['newtext'] = data['CleanedText'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
```